# Microsoft Word Stuck in Save As Loop

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I have a Microsoft Word document that is populated with content controls including repeating section content controls (~600 total). Filling forms editing restrictions are in place on the document. When users add several lines to the repeating section content control in one particular section (each repeating entry contains 8 content control fields) and fill in the content controls then try to save the document they are thrown an error whereby instead of saving the document when they click save they are directed to the save as file dialog box where they get stuck in an endless loop trying to save the document. The user cannot save the file to the same file name or to a different file name, both local folders and network folders have been tried as save locations. Additionally I have tried saving the document as a macro-enabled .docm file, and this too did not work

One similar issue I found was here:[Endless save loop in Microsoft Word](https://superuser.com/questions/603393/endless-save-loop-in-microsoft-word)

However, using the solution provided for that question would result in the document's content controls becoming static which is not an option. I am using Microsoft Word 2016 (in which the form was developed) as are the users who brought this issue to my attention. There are further users who use Microsoft Office 2013, but to date they have not yet had issues

**Update: I have found a work around, whereby the user saves the document after every line entry, this appears to address the issue but is not an ideal solution, any permanent solutions/help would be greatly appreciated**

Comment: could you solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Resetting your MS Word settings should fix the problem.

1. Run regedit as Administrator
2. Go to the following key
   `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word]`
3. Delete it (the `Word` key)

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution by hitting "save and send", then send using email / send as attachment; Word then says it found some errors in my document, but was able to fix them. Then I send the document to myself. Using the self-emailed version, have found no issues so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a problem with old and new versions of Word being incompatible. Try saving it as a .doc file and then re-save it as a .docx file. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!
The problem is because of some specific type of content in the document, such as some specific figure formats. All you need to do is delete some of your content and try to save it in docx. if it is saved, then the problem is in deleted content. Proceed till you isolate that one component and rewrite or reinsert figure for that one component. It  takes few minutes to figure it out but works brilliantly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found another workaround, which also happens to be kind of easy. When the 'Save As' dialogue box shows up, at the bottom of the window click on 'Maintain compatibility with previous versions of Word'. I don't know if it will work for everyone, but worked for me.